# Why my form data not insert into my database without using input type="hidden"?

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli

Here is my db connection, form page, conform page. I will try to insert data into database without using any form. Someone please check my code.

**db.php**

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_form");
if(!$connect){
    die('Can not connect:'.mysqli_error());
}
else{
    echo "Connect";
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
?>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="f-name" placeholder="f-name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="l-name" placeholder="l-name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="bday" placeholder="bday"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="school" placeholder="school"><br><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female</label><br><br>
    <textarea name="hobby"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

All data show in process.php page but in this page click in Save btn it's not insert in database.

**process.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
?>

<?php
$fname=$_POST['f-name'];
$lname=$_POST['l-name'];
$bday=$_POST['bday'];
$school=$_POST['school'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$hobby=$_POST['hobby'];

echo "$fname"."<br>";
echo "$lname"."<br>";
echo "$bday"."<br>";
echo "$school"."<br>";
echo "$gender"."<br>";
echo "$hobby"."<br>";
?>
<button name="Sava" type="button" value="Save">Save</button>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['save'])){
    $sql="INSERT INTO test_table(f_name, l_name, b_day, school, gender, hobby) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$bday', '$school', '$gender', '$hobby')";
}

$query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if($query){
    $msg="Successfully Inserted...";
}else{
    $msg="Not Inserted...";
}
?>
<h1><?php echo $msg; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Why are you using button after submitting the form. ? Are you trying to give   user to review their details ? If not that Case you can directly Use Post Variables to Validate with DB Values.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click your "Save" button, your page is not reloaded. There is no form or JavaScript to do it.

However, even if you manage to reload page, former `$_POST` from your form is no longer valid for this reloaded page.

Also, you have a typo:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['save'])){ ...
```

but

```
<button name="Sava" type="button" value="Save">Save</button>
```

`save` should be `Sava`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert by checking `isset($_POST['submit'])`

or use `isset($_POST['what_ever_submit_button'])`

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
?>

<?php
$fname=$_POST['f-name'];
$lname=$_POST['l-name'];
//$_POST['submit'];

echo "$fname"."<br>";
echo "$lname"."<br>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql="INSERT INTO test_table(f_name, l_name) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";
}

$query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if($query){
    $msg="Successfully Inserted...";
}else{
    $msg="Not Inserted...";
}
?>
<h1><?php echo $msg; ?></h1>
```